# Magento 2 Full Page cache configuration in admin greyed out

Tags: admin, full-page-cache, magento-2.2.5

The Full Page Cache from -

> Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> system -> full page cache

It's greyed out, like in screenshot.

[image]

I have chosen Default config from Store View,

[image]

I was able to change this configuration earlier. I don't know what went wrong that this is greyed out now.

Answer (score 0):

Would say it's duplicate of [So many admin-related checkboxes grayed/greyed out in ALL scopes](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/321796/so-many-admin-related-checkboxes-grayed-greyed-out-in-all-scopes)
(basically, a static configuration in config files).